# Zebra print doesn't print my desired output

Tags: c#

Good day! I was trying to make a one click print on my app with zebra printer. If I print it with a different printer it prints my png file properly However, in Zebra it doesn't print properly.

Here's my code.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = GetDefaultPrinter();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true; //or false!
pd.PrintPage += (aw, args) =>
{

    Image i = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Coke\pres10.png");
    Rectangle m = args.MarginBounds;

    if ((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // image is wider
    {
        m.Height = (int)((double)i.Height / (double)i.Width * (double)m.Width);
    }
    else
    {
        m.Width = (int)((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height * (double)m.Height);
    }
    m.Width = m.Width;
    m.Height = m.Height;
    args.Graphics.DrawImage(i,m);
};
pd.Print();
```

Picture: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and do this . I am not sure if this works or not.

Step 1: Calculate the aspect ratio of the original image. Aspect ratio is the ratio of Height and width.You can use this [calculator](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/) for the calculations.Make sure you calculate for the original image and the final image.

Step 2 : Check whether there is a deviation in the aspect ratio . If yes then make sure to get the perfect aspect ratio for the screen.

Comment: How do I apply the aspect ratio?

Comment: there will be a factor when you divide the original height /original width ... multiply that factor...let me give you an example for this

Comment: Okay sir, please. Thank you so much!

Comment: can you look into this ?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180804/how-to-get-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image

Comment: I understand how the aspect works, however how would I apply it to my code?